# In SQL how to I exclude a record if there are more than 3 characters after a dash

Tags: sql

In SQL how do I exclude a record if there are more than 2 characters after a dash..

Example I only want to return records that match the following
 AA00000-0

but the table also has recoreds like AA0000-000,AA0000000-00

I need to return only records that have a single digit after the dash

Comment: For what database?  String comparison is not consistently supported across databases...

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, digit matching is not consistent across databases.

For SQL Server, you can do:

`MyColumn LIKE '%-[0-9]'` (will get it with only a digit after the dash)

Database-agnostic:

`MyColumn LIKE '%-_'` (would match a digit **or** 1 letter after the dash, but that may be sufficient)

Comment: +1/2 for being agnostic, and +1/2 for interpreting "single digit after the dash" to possibly included single character after dash.

Answer (score 0):

LIKE '%-[0-9]'

Filler Filler Filler Filler

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQL Server:

```
SELECT * FROM records WHERE id NOT LIKE '%-[0-9][0-9]%'
```

Comment: That would give two characters after the dash

Comment: Please can you elaborate. It should exclude records with 2 or more digits after a dash.

Answer (score 0):

Use a like statement.

`Field Like '%-[0-9]'`

Answer (score 0):

What database are you using?

In MSSQL you could: `where fld not like '%-__'`

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all the answers, the solution I used was

```
Like '%-_'
```

The single underscore represents the first digit after the dash